# Finding all distributions of A apples amongst B baskets

Tags: algorithm, optimization, recursion, combinatorics, combinations

We have A apples, B baskets.

How would you write the algorithm that lists every possible distribution for baskets.
One basket can contain zero or max apples.

For example: A = 6, B = 4 (6 apples, 4 baskets).

d1 = 6 0 0 0

d2 = 5 1 0 0

d3 = 5 0 1 0

d4 = 4 2 0 0

d5 = 3 0 0 3

.......

......
so on....

Comment: _One basket can contain zero or max apples._? Are you sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int basket[6];
void walk(int iBasket, int nRemain){
  if (iBasket == 6-1){
    basket[iBasket] = nRemain;
    // print baskets
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i <= nRemain; i++){
      basket[iBasket] = i;
      walk(iBasket+1, nRemain - i);
    }
  }
}

void main(){
  walk(0, 6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate them recursively by adding 0 to `apples_left` apples to the current bucket and returning all solutions for the current bucket + the remaining buckets with `apples_left` minus apples taken for this bucket. I think code explains it best here, so here's some Python code:

```
def allocations(apples, baskets):
  if baskets == 0:
    if apples == 0:
      yield []
    return
  for a in xrange(apples+1):
    for alloc in allocations(apples-a, baskets-1):
      yield [a] + alloc

for i, alloc in enumerate(allocations(6, 4)):
  print 'd%d = %s' % (i+1, ' '.join(map(str, alloc)))
```

Outputs

```
d1 = 0 0 0 6
d2 = 0 0 1 5
d3 = 0 0 2 4
d4 = 0 0 3 3
...
d83 = 5 1 0 0
d84 = 6 0 0 0
```

[Full output](http://ideone.com/7w0g0)

Answer (score 0):

```
int apples;
int baskets;
cin >> apples >> baskets;
vector<int>(apples + baskets - 1, 0);
for(int i = baskets - 1; i < apples + baskets - 1; ++i)
 v[i] = 1;
do
{
 //first basket untill 1st 0
 //second basket from 1st to 2nd 0
 //third basket from 2nd to 3th 0
 //...
 //last basket from (basket - 1)th 0 to the end of vector
}next_permutation(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need an optimized version, you can also use an algorithm for generating combinations, which is provided by libraries like Python's `itertools`.
See my answer to this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647120/next-composition-of-n-into-k-parts-does-anyone-have-a-working-algorithm)

```
from itertools import combinations, tee 


def diffed_tuple(t):
    t2, t1 = tee(t)
    for x in t2:
        break
    return tuple(e2 - e1 for e2, e1 in zip(t2, t1))



# --The Algorithm--
def compositions(n, k):
    for t in combinations(range(n+k), k+1):
        yield tuple(e-1 for e in diffed_tuple(t))
```