# Next Composition of n into k parts - does anyone have a working algorithm?

Tags: combinatorics

Composition of *n* into *k* parts - I want to list all the possible compositions of n into k parts - does anyone have an algorithm (preferably in R)?  Or know if it's in library anywhere?

For example, if I have *n* cubes, and *k* bags, and want to list all the possible arrangements of the cubes in the bags.  e.g. there are 3 ways you can arrange 2 cubes into 2 bags:

```
(2, 0) (1, 1) (0, 2)
```

I've found the NEXCOM alogarithm.  I've found a version of it [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/website/CombAlgDownld.html) (page 46) in Fortran, but don't code in Fortran so really understand what's going on - any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are attempting to list is called an *k*-multicombination. The problem is often stated this way: given *n indistinguishable* balls and *k* boxes, list all possible ways to distribute all of the balls in the boxes. The number of such distributions is:

```
factorial(n + k - 1) / (factorial(k - 1) * factorial(n))
```

For further background, see Method 4 of the [Twelve-Fold Way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Functions_from_N_to_X.2C_up_to_a_permutation_of_N).

Here is the code to enumerate the distributions (C++):

```
string & ListMultisets(unsigned au4Boxes, unsigned au4Balls, string & strOut = string ( ), string strBuild = string ( ))
{
    unsigned au4;
    if (au4Boxes > 1) for (au4 = 0; au4 <= au4Balls; au4++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << strBuild << (strBuild.size() == 0 ? "" : ",") << au4Balls - au4;
        ListMultisets (au4Boxes - 1, au4, strOut, ss.str ( ));
    }
    else
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "(" << strBuild << (strBuild.size() == 0 ? "" : ",") << au4Balls << ")\n";
        strOut += ss.str ( );
    }
    return strOut;
}



int main(int argc, char * [])
{    
    cout << endl << ListMultisets (3, 5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output from the above program (5 balls distributed over three boxes):

```
(5,0,0)
(4,1,0)
(4,0,1)
(3,2,0)
(3,1,1)
(3,0,2)
(2,3,0)
(2,2,1)
(2,1,2)
(2,0,3)
(1,4,0)
(1,3,1)
(1,2,2)
(1,1,3)
(1,0,4)
(0,5,0)
(0,4,1)
(0,3,2)
(0,2,3)
(0,1,4)
(0,0,5)
```

Comment: Isn't the equation `factorial(n * k * 1) / ( factorial(k - 1) * factorial(n))` ? I'm asking, because I just learned about weak compositions.

Comment: @MattMunson, the equation was correct for an _n_-multicombination, But I described a _k_-multicombination in the text. I made another edit to reflect the change.

Answer (score 8):

Since it took me a bit of effort to read the intention of the other c++ solution here a translation to python (also as generator result instead of string):

```py
def weak_compositions(boxes, balls, parent=tuple()):
  if boxes > 1:
    for i in xrange(balls + 1):
      for x in weak_compositions(boxes - 1, i, parent + (balls - i,)):
        yield x
  else:
    yield parent + (balls,)
```

test:

```py
>>> for x in weak_compositions(3, 5): print x
(5, 0, 0)
(4, 1, 0)
(4, 0, 1)
(3, 2, 0)
...
(0, 1, 4)
(0, 0, 5)
```

Comment: FWIW, I've added Python 3 versions of your code to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40540014/4014959) which uses `itertools.combinations` to generate weak partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Computing compositions (I ignore how standard the term is) and combinations is equivalent in a sense. There's a bijective function between combinations of `k + 1` in `n + k` and compositions of `n` into `k` parts. All one has to do is assign a number from 1 to `n` to each letter of the combinations, order the letters according to their number, then:

- make a tuple composed of the differences between numbers of consecutive letters
- subtract 1 to each entry of the tuple, and there you have it.

Assuming your algorithm for computing combinations yields combinations with 'ordered letters', then the rest is a trivial computation.

In Python:

```
from itertools import combinations, tee 
  #see: 
  #http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations
  #http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee
```

def diffed_tuple(t):
    # return a new tuple but where the entries are the differences
    # between consecutive entries of the original tuple.
    #make two iterator objects which yield entries from t in parallel
    t2, t1 = tee(t)
    # advance first iterator one step
    for x in t2:
        break
    # return a tuple made of the entries yielded by the iterators
    return tuple(e2 - e1 for e2, e1 in zip(t2, t1))

# --The Algorithm--
def compositions(n, k):
    for t in combinations(range(n+k), k+1):
        # yield the 'diffed tuple' but subtracting 1 from each entry
        yield tuple(e-1 for e in diffed_tuple(t))

Comment: I am not an expert so I hesitate to edit the answer, but I believe the algorithm given here computes [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), rather than compositions.  The difference is that zero is as a possible element of a weak composition, but not of a composition.

Comment: Actually, I think this algorithm doesn't work at all.  `compositions(2, 3)` returns a generator over,

    (0, 0, 0)
    (0, 0, 1)
    (0, 1, 0)
    (1, 0, 0)
    (0, 0, 0)

These are _not_ the compositions of 2, and one of them is repeated!

Answer (score 0):

I've made the translation of the original NEXCOM algorithm to structured Fortran and Java. The Java version is:

```
public void allCombinations(final int n, final int k) {
    final int[] input = new int[k + 1];
    Boolean mtc = Boolean.FALSE;
    int t = n;
    int h = 0;
    do {
        if (mtc) {
            if (t > 1) {
                h = 0;
            }
            h++;
            t = input[h];
            input[h] = 0;
            input[1] = t - 1;
            input[h + 1]++;
        } else {
            // First permutation is always n00...0 i.e. it's a descending
            // series lexicographically.
            input[1] = n;
            for (int i = 2; i <= k; i++) {
                input[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(input));
        mtc = input[k] != n;
    } while (mtc);
}
```