# Generate all compositions of an integer into k parts

Tags: combinatorics

I can't figure out how to generate all compositions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29) of an integer N into K parts, but only doing it one at a time. That is, I need a function that given the previous composition generated, returns the next one in the sequence. The reason is that memory is limited for my application. This would be much easier if I could use Python and its generator functionality, but I'm stuck with C++.

This is similar to [Next Composition of n into k parts - does anyone have a working algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647120/next-composition-of-n-into-k-parts-does-anyone-have-a-working-algorithm)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

start with the array [1,1,...,1,N-k+1] of (K-1) ones and 1 entry with the remainder. The next composition can be created by incrementing the (K-1)th element and decreasing the last element. Do this trick as long as the last element is bigger than the second to last.

When the last element becomes smaller, increment the (K-2)th element, set the (K-1)th element to the same value and set the last element to the remainder again. Repeat the process and apply the same principle for the other elements when necessary.

You end up with a constantly sorted array that avoids duplicate compositions

Answer (score 4):

## Preliminary remarks

First start from the observation that [1,1,...,1,n-k+1] is the first composition (in lexicographic order) of n over k parts, and [n-k+1,1,1,...,1] is the last one.

Now consider an exemple: the composition [2,4,3,1,1], here n = 11 and k=5. Which is the next one in lexicographic order? Obviously the rightmost part to be incremented is 4, because [3,1,1] is the last composition of 5 over 3 parts.

4 is at the left of 3, the rightmost part different from 1.

So turn 4 into 5, and replace [3,1,1] by [1,1,2], the first composition of the remainder (3+1+1)-1 , giving [2,5,1,1,2]

## Generation program (in C)

The following C program shows how to compute such compositions *on demand* in lexicographic order

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool get_first_composition(int n, int k, int composition[k])
{
    if (n < k) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        composition[i] = 1;
    }
    composition[k - 1] = n - k + 1;
    return true;
}

bool get_next_composition(int n, int k, int composition[k])
{
    if (composition[0] == n - k + 1)    {
        return false;
    }
    // there'a an i with composition[i] > 1, and it is not 0.
    // find the last one
    int last = k - 1;
    while (composition[last] == 1) {
        last--;
    }
    // turn    a b ...   y   z 1 1 ...   1
    //                       ^ last
    // into    a b ... (y+1) 1 1 1 ... (z-1)

    // be careful, there may be no 1's at the end

    int z = composition[last];
    composition[last - 1] += 1;
    composition[last] = 1;
    composition[k - 1] = z - 1;
    return true;
}

void display_composition(int k, int composition[k])
{
    char *separator = "[";
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        printf("%s%d", separator, composition[i]);
        separator = ",";
    }
    printf("]\n");
}


void display_all_compositions(int n, int k)
{
    int composition[k];  // VLA. Please don't use silly values for k
    for (bool exists = get_first_composition(n, k, composition);
            exists;
            exists = get_next_composition(n, k, composition)) {
        display_composition(k, composition);
    }
}

int main()
{
    display_all_compositions(5, 3);
}
```

Results

```
[1,1,3]
[1,2,2]
[1,3,1]
[2,1,2]
[2,2,1]
[3,1,1]
```

## Weak compositions

A similar algorithm works for weak compositions (where 0 is allowed).

```c
bool get_first_weak_composition(int n, int k, int composition[k])
{
    if (n < k) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < k - 1; i++) {
        composition[i] = 0;
    }
    composition[k - 1] = n;
    return true;
}

bool get_next_weak_composition(int n, int k, int composition[k])
{
    if (composition[0] == n)    {
        return false;
    }
    // there'a an i with composition[i] > 0, and it is not 0.
    // find the last one
    int last = k - 1;
    while (composition[last] == 0) {
        last--;
    }
    // turn    a b ...   y   z 0 0 ...   0
    //                       ^ last
    // into    a b ... (y+1) 0 0 0 ... (z-1)

    // be careful, there may be no 0's at the end

    int z = composition[last];
    composition[last - 1] += 1;
    composition[last] = 0;
    composition[k - 1] = z - 1;
    return true;
}
```

Results for n=5 k=3

```
[0,0,5]
[0,1,4]
[0,2,3]
[0,3,2]
[0,4,1]
[0,5,0]
[1,0,4]
[1,1,3]
[1,2,2]
[1,3,1]
[1,4,0]
[2,0,3]
[2,1,2]
[2,2,1]
[2,3,0]
[3,0,2]
[3,1,1]
[3,2,0]
[4,0,1]
[4,1,0]
[5,0,0]
```

Similar algorithms can be written for compositions of n into k parts greater than some fixed value.