# variable number of dependent nested loops

Tags: python, nested-loops, integer-partition

Given two integers `n` and `d`, I would like to construct a list of all nonnegative tuples of length `d` that sum up to `n`, including all permutations. This is similar to the [integer partitioning problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning), but the solution is much simpler. For example for 
`d==3`:

```
[
    [n-i-j, j, i]
    for i in range(n+1)
    for j in range(n-i+1)
]
```

This can be extended to more dimensions quite easily, e.g., `d==5`:

```
[
    [n-i-j-k-l, l, k, j, i]
    for i in range(n+1)
    for j in range(n-i+1)
    for k in range(n-i-j+1)
    for l in range(n-i-j-l+1)
]
```

I would now like to make `d`, i.e., the number of nested loops, a variable, but I'm not sure how to nest the loops then.

Any hints?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible in a list comprehension as such but perhaps you could keep track of the subtracted values somehow so then all your loops look like `for val in range(n - sum(vals) + 1)` and then loop over that `d` times while building the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Next Composition of n into k parts - does anyone have a working algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647120/next-composition-of-n-into-k-parts-does-anyone-have-a-working-algorithm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recursion to the rescue: First create a list of tuples of length `d-1` which runs through all `ijk`, then complete the list with another column `n-sum(ijk)`.

```
def partition(n, d, depth=0):
    if d == depth:
        return [[]]
    return [
        item + [i]
        for i in range(n+1)
        for item in partition(n-i, d, depth=depth+1)
        ]


# extend with n-sum(entries)
n = 5
d = 3
lst = [[n-sum(p)] + p for p in partition(n, d-1)]

print(lst)
```

Comment: Nice, I don't know why I was thinking of doing it iteratively.

Comment: Yeah, same. Thinking about this iteratively had me stuck for the better part of the day.